# Change data size of all columns with same column name in sql developer data modeler

Tags: oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have a column USER_ID in almost 100 Tables. I have both relational and logical models in Sql developer data modeler(4.2)

I need to change data size from  varchar2(5) to varchar2(10)

How can i do this in 1 shot instead of manually changing the size 200 times.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.  The first method would have been proactive, defining a domain for that.  The second way is to create a custom transformation that will go through all the tables in your model, look for any occurrence of a USER_ID column, then adjust its datatype accordingly.  Kris Rice's blog was a great source of information when I had to create my own custom scripts: http://krisrice.blogspot.com/search?updated-max=2011-02-02T16%3A49%3A00-08%3A00&max-results=3